# Problems running python program with srvany.exe

Tags: python, windows, sockets, service, tcp

I must preface this with a full disclaimer that i'm very early in my python development days

I've made a simple python program that waits for a socket connection to the local ip address over port 20000. When it gets a connection, it pops up a message alert using the win32api.

```
#tcpintercomserver.py
import socket
import sys
import win32api

ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

#socket creation
sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

#Binding
server_address = (ip, 20000)
sock.bind(server_address)
print server_address

#Listen
sock.listen(1)

while True:
# Wait for a connection
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()
    win32api.MessageBox(0,'MessageText','Titletext', 0x00001000)
    # Close Connection
    connection.close()
```

I also have a mated client program that simply connects to the socket. The script takes an argument of the host you're trying to reach (DNS name or ip address)

```
#tcpintercomcli.py

import socket
import sys

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect the socket to the port where the server is listening
server_address = (sys.argv[1], 20000)
sock.connect(server_address)
```

This all runs fine as scripts. I then used CX_Freeze to turn them into executables. Both run just like they did when they were scripts.

Now i've taken the server script and connected it to a service with srvany.exe and use of the SC command in windows.

I set up the service using SC create "intercom" binPath= "C:\dist\srvany.exe"

Under the intercom service key in the registry, i've added the Parameter's key, and under there set Application to a string value c:\dist\tcpintercomserver.exe

I then perform a "net start intercom" and the service launches successfully, and the tcpintercomserver.exe is listed as a running process. However, when i run the tcpintercomcli.py or tcpintercomcli.exe, no alert comes up.

I'm baffled...is there something with the CX_Freeze process that may be messing this up?

Answer (score 0):

Service process cannot show messagebox, they don't have access to UI, they usually run as SYSTEM user. if you are running from service, proper way of debugging and showing messages are using EventLog.
See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows Vista or later, your script is running headlong into [Session 0 Isolation](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#WhatIsSession0Isolation) -- where GUI elements from a Windows service are not shown on an interactive user's desktop.

You will probably see your message box if you [switch to session 0](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/SwitchToSession0/)...